# Create a combined array based on two array of objects in NODE JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I have two arrays of objects

```
const leads = [{Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234} ,  {Week: 2 , PackageId: 5678}  ]           
const arrayOfTargets = [{Key : 1 , Count: 20} ,  {Key: 2 , Count: 30}  ]
```

I want to add each object of target to the leads and create a new array that combines them.

For example the new array would look like :

```
const combined =    [
    {Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234 , Key : 1 , Count: 20} ,  
    {Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234 , Key : 2 , Count: 30} ,  
    {Week: 2 , PackageId: 5678 , Key: 1 , Count: 20} ,  
    {Week: 2 , PackageId: 5678 , Key: 2 , Count: 30} 

];
```

I tried to do a double mapping :

```
   const result = arrayOfTargets.map(target => {
          return leads.map(lead => ({
            Week: lead.Week,
            PackageId: lead.PackageId,               
            TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType: target.Key,
            CopiesToBeClaimedByClientType: target.Count,              
          }));
        });
```

But when I console.log that I get empty objects.

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: why twice same objects (content wise) in the result set?

Comment: @NinaScholz: Where do you see the same objects ? Two different objects : `leads` and `arrayOfTargets`

Comment: *"But when I console.log that I get empty objects"*. That is not possible. Your `map` code has keys like `TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType` while the `combined` doesn't have that. You have asked ~500 questions yet still haven't posted a [mcve]

Comment: please have a look to `combined`, where you have double same objects.

Comment: Please check the `combined` object. It is unclear what your expected behavior is.

Comment: @NinaScholz and @adiga 's question is `const combined =    [
    {Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234 , Key : 1 , Count: 20} ,  
    {Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234 , Key : 1 , Count: 20} ,  
    {Week: 2 , PackageId: 5678 , Key: 2 , Count: 30} ,  
    {Week: 2 , PackageId: 5678 , Key: 2 , Count: 30} 

];`  why there are two objects with the same value in the combined array.

Comment: You need `arrayOfTargets.flatMap` instead of just `map`, otherwise your code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fine and it works perfectly. Just use `flat` function to flat array:

```js
const leads = [
{ Week: 1, PackageId: 1234 },
{ Week: 2, PackageId: 5678 }
];
const arrayOfTargets = [
{ Key: 1, Count: 20 },
{ Key: 2, Count: 30 }
];

const result = arrayOfTargets.map(target => {
return leads.map(lead => ({
  Week: lead.Week,
  PackageId: lead.PackageId,
  TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType: target.Key,
  CopiesToBeClaimedByClientType: target.Count,
}));
  });

  console.log(result.flat());
```

In addition, it can be done using `reduce`, `foreach` methods like that:

```js
const leads = [
{ Week: 1, PackageId: 1234 },
{ Week: 2, PackageId: 5678 }
];
const arrayOfTargets = [
{ Key: 1, Count: 20 },
{ Key: 2, Count: 30 }
];

const result = leads.reduce((a, {Week, PackageId}, index) => {
a[Week] = a[Week] || {values:[]};

arrayOfTargets.forEach(f => {
    a[Week].values.push({ Week, PackageId, ...f});
});

return a;
}, {});


console.log(Object.values(result).flatMap(f=> f.values));
```

Answer (score -1):

map is return an array of the same length of the array that you are mapping 
try creating empty array and push the result of each iteration on it

```
let result=[]
leads.map(i=>{
    arrayOfTargets.map(j=>{
result.push({...i,...j}) 
})
})
```

Comment: They are not the same length

Answer (score -1):

You can use the index variable in map to match 1 array with the 2nd like this:

```
const leads = [{Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234} ,  {Week: 2 , PackageId: 5678}  ]           
const arrayOfTargets = [{Key : 1 , Count: 20} ,  {Key: 2 , Count: 30}  ]

leads.map((x,i)=> { return {...x, ...arrayOfTargets[i]};})
```

in es6 you got the spread operator for objects, what this does is spread the inside variables out. 

this results in :

```
//pre spread    
return {...x, ...arrayOfTargets[i]};}
//post spread
return {Week : 1 , PackageId: 1234, Key : 1 , Count: 20}
```

see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Thanks , however it doesn't spread all the records , only 2 out of 4.